# JavaScript: How to get string between brackets

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to get a string in between a bracket opened `(` and a bracket closed `)`.

```
myString = "MT Mokwa (40,000)"
```

How can I get `40,000` from the string?

Comment: Use a regular expression. Or even just `indexOf` and `substring`

Comment: If the format is always similar you could use a reg ex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: Please show us that you've at least done some research into this, as requested in [ask]; "Search and research".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of these examples assume that the string will always have a set of parenthesis, opening before closing.

I suggest using [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for this:

```
var result = myString.substring( myString.indexOf( '(' ) + 1, myString.indexOf( ')' ) );
```

You can also use a regex if you prefer:

```
var result = /\(([^)]*)\)/.exec(myString)[1];
```